# How to copy related row data from Google Sheets remote tab or Sheet into current Sheet with a script?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I could use IMPORTRANGE, but I want to actually place the values themselves into the cells, instead. For sheets with many rows, a lot of IMPORTRANGE formulas can cause lag and slow down performance.

Is there a way to copy data from a row in another sheet that has the same ID number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is an example of how to do this.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OvbSwL6wVHKnBsG1AWx0uAY-jhqe58eTjbXQ5cy0omE/edit#gid=0) When "update" or "edit" is selected from the dropdown boxes, data from the other, designated tab's rows are copied into the current sheet.

Here is the script:

```
function onEdit(e) {

////UPDATE ROWS WITH DATA FROM REMOTE SHEET VIA SCRIPT
///the script below is adapted from https://mashe.hawksey.info/2015/03/google-sheets-move-a-row-of-data-to-another-sheet-based-on-cell-value/
  // see Sheet event objects docs
  // https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events
var ss = e.source;
var s = ss.getSheetByName("Animals List");
var r = e.range;
var remoteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("List B");

  // to let you modify where the action and move columns are in the form responses sheet
var actionCol = 1;

  // Get the row and column of the active cell.
var rowIndex = r.getRowIndex();
var colIndex = r.getColumnIndex();
  // Get the number of columns in the active sheet.
  // -1 to drop our action/status column
var colNumber = s.getLastColumn()-1;

var curNumberCell = s.getRange(rowIndex,2, 1, 1);
var curIDNumber =  curNumberCell.getValue();
var curDCell = s.getRange(rowIndex,4, 1, 1);
var curECell = s.getRange(rowIndex,5, 1, 1);

 // if our action/status col is changed to update or edit, do stuff
if (e.value == "update" || "edit" && colIndex == actionCol) {

 //THE FOLLOWING REPLACES THE FORMULAS OF THE ROW WITH THEIR GENERATED VALUES - UNCOMMENT TO USE:
 //var sourceRange = s.getRange(rowIndex, 1, 1, colNumber);
 //sourceRange.setValues(sourceRange.getValues());


///Retrieve data from remote tab/sheet that has matching cell value
var values = remoteSheet.getDataRange().getValues(); //IN REMOTE SHEET WE NEED TO SEARCH ENTIRE SHEET

for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
   if (values[i][0] == curIDNumber )
   {
   curDCell.setValue(values[i][1] );
   curECell.setValue(values[i][2] );
   }
   }    
} //end retrieve remote data
}
```